# Perform operation when column visibility changes with DTOptionsBuilder, ColVis using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

I am using DTOptionsBuilder with ColVis plugin for datatable+ show and hide columns in AngularJs.
I want to perform some operations upon change in visibility of the columns.
I found an event 'column-visibility.dt' which notifies columns visibility is changed.
So I want to do something like below in Angular way but puzzled how.

```
$('#example').dataTable();

$('#example').on( 'column-visibility.dt', function ( e, settings, column, state ) {
    console.log(
        'Column '+ column +' has changed to '+ (state ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    );
} );
```

Comment: Forgot to post the answer...problem was solved, there is an option to add callback function on State change of the columns as below while initializing colvis plugin:-
  var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis(table, {
                        buttonText: '  ',
                        align: 'right',
                        exclude: _excludeColumns,
                        stateChange: function(iColumn, bVisible) {
                          console.log('Column '+iColumn+' set to '+ bVisible);
                          //Do the stuff here
                        }
                    });

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved, there is an option to add callback function on State change of the columns as below while initializing colvis plugin:-

```
var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis(table, {
     buttonText: '  ',
     align: 'right',
     exclude: _excludeColumns,
     stateChange: function(iColumn, bVisible) {
         console.log('Column '+iColumn+' set to '+ bVisible);
         //Do the stuff here
     }
});
```